# Can this method be used to find the smallest real number $a_n$ that satisfies this inequality?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Is there an easier way of solving this problem by using calculus, perhaps creating an equation $a_n = max(f(n,x))$, and finding the maximum of $f$ using calculus?

**Problem.**
Let $n$ be a positive integer, and set $N = 2^n$. Determine the smallest real number $a_n$ such that, for all real $x$,
$$\sqrt[N]{\frac{x^{2N}+1}{2}}\leq a_n (x-1)^2 + x$$

**Answer.**
$$a_n = N/2 = 2^{n-1}$$

**Attempt.**
$$\sqrt[N]{\frac{x^{2N}+1}{2}}\leq a_n (x-1)^2 + x$$
for $x>0$,
$$\implies \sqrt[N]{\frac{\text {some positive number}+1}{2}}\leq a_n (\text {some positive number})^2 + \text {some positive number}$$

I find that
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \Biggr[a_n (x-1)^2 + x -\sqrt[N]{\frac{x^{2N}+1}{2}}\Biggr]\geq0$$
By L'hopital's rule (assuming $a_n$ is positive):
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n (x-1)^2 + x }{\sqrt[N]{\frac{x^{2N}+1}{2}}} =: \geq 1$$
$$=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2a_n (x-1) + 1 }{2^{1-(1/n)} x^{2n-1} (x^{2n}+1)^{1/(n-1)}}$$
$$=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2a_n}{2^{1-2^{-n}} x^{2^{n+1}-1} (x^{2^{n+1}}+1)^{2^{-n}-1}}$$
I'm pretty sure it's obvious that as $x$ approaches $\infty$, $x^{2^{n+1}-1}$ will become large at a rate that is slower than the rate at which $(x^{2^{n+1}}+1)^{2^{-n}-1}$ becomes small, but not sure how to prove that. Could I use L'Hopital's rule on $x^{2^{n+1}-1} \cdot (x^{2^{n+1}}+1)^{2^{-n}-1}$? And, of course, $2^{1-2^{-n}}$ will always be $\leq 2$. That means that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \Biggr[a_n (x-1)^2 + x -\sqrt[N]{\frac{x^{2N}+1}{2}}\Biggr]\geq0 \text{ for all positive } a_n.$$

The question remains how to prove that for the other values of $x$, the expression is true, and how to find (the way it makes sense to me) a curve of minimum values $a_n$ must take on for the expression to be true, then take the derivative of that curve to find the inflection point where its maximum is, and find that maximum to be the point at which $a_n=N/2=2^{n-1}$. Is my thought process correct? Unfortunately their solution doesn't make much sense to me. I can wrap my head around it, but there's no way I'd be able to come up with it when looking at this problem on a test.

---

**Solution Given.**

[image]

What is happening in the step "Expanding the brackets we get"? It looks like both sides of the inequality were multiplied by $-1$ then the right side was added to the left side. Then the $\geq$ (needs to be $\geq$ because you invert the inequality when multiplying by a negative) was turned into $=$ and a bunch of terms were added to the right side.

Can their solution be explained, and can you comment on the efficacy of my approach? Is there a way to (somewhat) easily create a curve of $a_n = f(n,x)$ and find the maximum of that function, to find the value of $a_n$, and how would you do so?

This question is from the 2020 International Math Olympiad shortlist [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyVsA.png).

Comment: In the given solution, $(1)$ represents $(RHS)-(LHS)$. The solution shows that $(RHS)-(LHS)$ is negative for sufficiently small $t$. This contradicts $(LHS)\le (RHS)$.

Comment: Your solution is completely irrelevant (didn't check details). Even if you showed that the limit of $ f(x) $ is non-negative, that doesn't mean that $ f(x) \geq 0 $ at every point. In fact,$f(x)  =  - 1/x$ is a function whose value is always negative, but whose limit at infinity is non-negative.